# Discrete set of zeroes of polynomials must be finite?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, several-complex-variables

Let  $F:\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C^n$ be a polynomial mapping (i.e. $n$ polynomials in $n$ variables).

Suppose that $Z = \left\{z \in \mathbb C^n : F(z) = 0\right\}$ is a discrete set (all points are isolated).

1. I think $Z$ must be finite. How to prove this?
2. Also, is it true that a sufficient condition for $Z$ to be discrete is that $\det \left(\frac {\partial F_i}{\partial z_j}(z)\right) \ne 0$ for all $z \in Z$? I think this is true by the complex version of the Implicit Function Theorem (for instance, Proposition 1.1.11 in *Complex Geometry - An Introduction* by D. Huybrechts).

Comment: $\mathbb  C^n$ is allegorically clos. Then if $\deg F$ is finite, there is at most $\deg F$ solution.

Comment: @idm I don't understand. $\mathbb{C}^n$ is not a field, it's a vector space... By Bezout's theorem if $Z$ is finite then it has at most $\deg F_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot \deg F_n$ values, but I don't know it's finite, only that it's discrete.

Comment: Hint: for a discrete set, finite is equivalent to bounded.

Comment: @Crostul, that's a good point, but each $F_i$ has a zero set that is, in general, not bounded. For instance $f(x,y) = x-y$ has not at all a bounded zero set. It is not clear to me why the intersection must be bounded, once it is discrete.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't really pertain to my question as I am considering intersections of several zero sets, which *can* be discrete...

Comment: @Krokop this is irrelevant, my $F$ is a multivariate function.

Comment: @YoniRozenshein I deleted my previous comment, I misunderstood, sorry. If we take $Z=\left\{z \in \mathbb C^n : F(z) = 0\right\}$ is not finite using the example $g(x,y)=(xy,y)$ or $f(x,y)=(x-y,y-x)$ but isolated zeros are finite.

Comment: @Krokop I think you misunderstood the question. I am asking whether **if you suppose** $Z$ is discrete then is it finite? I edited the question to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yoni

Dear Yoni.

Because your claim deals with polynomial maps but would fail for holomorphic maps, I consider your claim a problem from algebraic geometry.

ad 1) Your assumption implies that the only irreducible components of the algebraic variety $Z \subset \mathbb A_{\mathbb C}^n$ are single points. But any algebraic variety has only finitely many irreducible components.

ad 2) Because of the condition on the functional matrix the algebraic variety $Z$ is non-singular and has dimension $=0$ at each of its points. Hence each irreducible component of $Z$ is $0-$dimensional. Finiteness of $Z$ follows from part 1).

Comment: Thanks! I suspected the answer might be something like this. But I don't really know algebraic geometry so there are two things I still don't understand (probably very trivial): 1. Why isn't an infinite subset of $Z$ irreducible? 2. Why is every algebraic variety a finite union of irreducible components?

Comment: @Yoni, I am not sure: Are you aware that algebraic varieties carry the Zariski topology, which is coarser than the usual Euclidean topology? In case you are not yet familiar with the Zariski topology I would recommend it - and the Noetherian property mentioned by zen - as a good starting point for algebraic geometry.

Comment: I know about the Zariski topology, but I don't know much about it beyond the basic definitions, particularly why an infinite 0-dimensional set cannot be irreducible.

Comment: @Yoni, the point of part 1) of my original answer is: Z is an algebraic variety. An algebraic variety has only finitely many irreducible components. Each point of Z is an irreducible component. Hence Z has only finitely many points. To which part of the chain of my arguments do you refer?

Comment: It does not seem to follow by logic alone. I understand that a point is irreducible. But what if some infinite sets of points were also irreducible? Maybe there is somehow a Zariski-closed discrete set such that removing 1 point makes it no longer Zariski-closed, and thus, it is irreducible? It would not logically contradict that Z has finitely many irreducible components if Z were such a set. I am missing another piece of the puzzle, which is that an infinite discrete set cannot be irreducible.

Comment: @Yoni I am not quite clear about what your point is. But if you ask for a proof that any of the finitely many  irreducible components of Z contains only finitely many points: If R denotes the coordinate ring of an irreducible component Y of Z, then R is a zero-dimensional ring. Furthermore the zero-ideal of R is prime, because the component is irreducible. Because R is zero-dimensional, its zero-ideal is maximal, hence R is a field. Hence Y is a single point. We have proved: Every irreducible component of Z consists of a single point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more ring-theoretic alternative to jo wehler's geometric answer. Let $F : \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ be given by $F = (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$, where $f_i \in \mathbb{C}[z_1, \ldots, z_n]$.

1) The zero set $Z$ is in bijection with the set of maximal ideals of $R := \mathbb{C}[z_1, \ldots, z_n]/(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$, and $Z$ is discrete iff $R$ has dimension $0$ (i.e. every point of $\text{Spec}(R)$ is closed). But $R$ is Noetherian, so $\dim R = 0$ iff $R$ is Artinian, and an Artinian ring has finitely many prime ideals.

2) Your condition on the Jacobian is equivalent to requiring the variety $Z$ to be nonsingular, which implies that it is (locally) a complete intersection, and thus has codimension $n$ ($= \#$ of equations), so $\dim Z = 0$ is discrete.

Comment: Unfortunately I lack a lot of the algebraic background, and find it hard to think about my problem in terms of ideals, spectrums, Noetherian and Artinian conditions... So for now I prefer jo wehler's answer. Thanks!